# escape control characters in unicode in python2 module

Tags: python, escaping, python-unicode, unicode-string

Here is a solution to escape only control characters in a unicode string.

```
control_chars = [unichr(c) for c in range(0x20)] # you may extend this as required

def control_escape2(s):
    return u''.join([c.encode('unicode_escape') if c in control_chars else c for c in s])
```

[Which is the correct way to encode escape characters in Python 2 without killing Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778550/which-is-the-correct-way-to-encode-escape-characters-in-python-2-without-killing)

This sounds to be a feature that may be worthwhile to put a module so that I don't have to always copy the same code around. Is there anything like this in existing python modules?

Comment: Can you give us a before-and-after example of the transformation you want?

Comment: One of the answers to your linked question says this: "*There should be a way to do this in the python stdlib, but there is not. I filed a bug report: http://bugs.python.org/issue18679*".

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no: per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19016117/3474146), the `unicodedata` module has utilities related to this, but it does not have an `escape_control_characters()` function natively.